# Unsupported Oracle data type 101 encountered

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g

```
OracleDataAdapter oAdp = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, SourceConnStr);
oAdp.Fill(dtTable);
```

On execution of this code I get the error:

```
Unsupported Oracle data type 101 encountered.
```

So I searched about the same and turns out .NET currently doesn't support or identify binary float/double and one of the columns in the table it is referring to; is of the datatype binary double. Please suggest a way to identify if a column of the table is of the datatype binary float/double and cast it to a different datatype like number or varchar which ever is appropriate.

```
Name           Null     Type          
-------------- -------- -------------       
EMPID          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)  
EMPNAME        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)  
EMPTYPE        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)    
EMPPHOTO                BINARY_DOUBLE  
DATEOFJOINING           DATE                 
CONTACTNO               VARCHAR2(20)
```

Comment: show table structre

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam I have just edited the question hope that helps

Comment: Which DataAcces library are you using? System.Data.OracleClient or  Oracle.DataAccess.Client or  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client ?

Comment: @Arie System.Data.OracleClient

Comment: System.Data.OracleClient is deprecated. Since BINARY_DOUBLE  and BINARY_FLOAT were added in Oracle Database 10g it is probably not supported.

Comment: If you were willing to change providers, here is the list of type mappings for Oracle.DataAccess.dll and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featData.htm#ODPNT284 (you can install ManagedDataAccess with nuget, although I don't know how complicated migrating the code from System.Data.OracleClient may prove to be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Identify structure:

   ```
   select * from all_tab_columns where data_type  like 'BINARY%' ;
   ```
2. workaround:
   In your `select`, replace the column with data conversion using e.g. `TO_CHAR`:

   ```
   new OracleDataAdapter("select column_a, column_b, to_char(column_c_binary_smthg) from " 
       + TABLE_NAME, SourceConnStr);
   ```

Comment: The problem here is that the user chooses which table to operate on and hence I cannot just randomly convert a single column on assumption. It has to dynamically identify which column is causing the problem and rectify the same

Comment: Yes, of course. Use same table to list which columns are in TABLE_NAME: `"select column_name from all_tab_columns where  TABLE_name=" + TABLE_NAME`

Answer (score 2):

Which `OracleDataAdapter` you use ? I guess it's from `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter` , if you are working with Oracle DB, use ODAC ,  `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter`, it works fine with oracle datatypes.